# Plane character selector unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm stuck in the past two days in how to do a character selection with a buying button by the guldens , the toggling works fine but there's something wrong with the character here's screenshot's .

I want when i toggle right or left to be in the same position and i tried to much to fix this and till now there's no result

[image]

When i toggle left or right its look like this

[image]

Here's my code

That's the MenuScene scrpit

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MenuScene : MonoBehaviour {

    private CanvasGroup fadeGroup;
    private float fadeInSpeed = 0.33f;

    public RectTransform menuContainer;
    public Transform levelPanel;
    public Transform colorPanel;
    public Transform trailPanel;

    public Button tiltControlButton; // Change the name of the button
    public Color tiltControlEnabled;
    public Color tiltControlDisabled;

    public Text buyColorText;
    public Text buyTrailText;
    public Text goldText;

    private MenuCamera menuCam;

    private int[] colorCost = new int[] { 0, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 10, 0, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10};
    private int[] trailCost = new int[] { 0, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10 };
    private int selectedColorIndex;
    private int selectedTrailIndex;
    private int activeColorIndex;
    private int activeTrailIndex;

    private Vector3 desiredMenuPosition;

    private GameObject currentTrail;

    public AnimationCurve enteringLevelZoomCurve;
    private bool isEnteringLevel = false;
    private float zoomDuration = 3.0f;
    private float zoomTransition;


  private void Start()
    {

        // Check if we have an accelerometer
        if(SystemInfo.supportsAccelerometer)
        {
            // It is currently enabled ?
            tiltControlButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = (SaveManager.Instance.state.usingAccelerometer) ? tiltControlEnabled : tiltControlDisabled;
        }
        else
        {
            tiltControlButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        //Find the only MenuCamera and assign it
        menuCam = FindObjectOfType<MenuCamera>();


        // Position our camera on the focused menu
        SetCameraTo(Manager.Instance.menuFocus);

        // Tell our gold text how much he should displaying 
        UpdateGoldText();
        //Grab the only canvasGroup in the scene 
        fadeGroup = FindObjectOfType<CanvasGroup>();

        //Start with a white screen 
        fadeGroup.alpha = 1;

        // Add button on-click events to shop buttons
        InItShop();

        //Add button on-Click events to levels 
        InitLevel();

        // Set players prefrences ( color & trail )
        OnColorSelect(SaveManager.Instance.state.activeColor);
        SetColor(SaveManager.Instance.state.activeColor);

        OnTrailSelect(SaveManager.Instance.state.activeTrail);
        SetTrail(SaveManager.Instance.state.activeTrail);

        // Make the buttons bigger for the selected items
        colorPanel.GetChild(SaveManager.Instance.state.activeColor).GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = Vector3.one * 1.125f;
        trailPanel.GetChild(SaveManager.Instance.state.activeTrail).GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = Vector3.one * 1.125f;

        // Create the trail preview 
        /*lastpreviewObject = GameObject.Instantiate(Manager.Instance.playertrails[SaveManager.Instance.state.activeTrail]) as GameObject;
        lastpreviewObject.transform.SetParent(trailPreviewObject);
        lastpreviewObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;*/

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Fade-in
        fadeGroup.alpha = 1 - Time.timeSinceLevelLoad * fadeInSpeed;

        //Menu navigation
        menuContainer.anchoredPosition3D = Vector3.Lerp(menuContainer.anchoredPosition3D, desiredMenuPosition, 0.1f);

        // Entering level zoom
        if(isEnteringLevel)
        {
            // Add to the zoomTransition float 
            zoomTransition += (1 / zoomDuration) * Time.deltaTime;

            // Change the scale, following the animation curve 
            menuContainer.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.one, Vector3.one * 5, enteringLevelZoomCurve.Evaluate(zoomTransition));

            // Change the desired position of the canvas , so it can follow the scale up
            // This zooms in the center 
            Vector3 newDesiredPosition = desiredMenuPosition * 5;
            // This adds to the specific position of the level on the canvas 
            RectTransform rt = levelPanel.GetChild(Manager.Instance.currentLevel).GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            newDesiredPosition -= rt.anchoredPosition3D * 5;

            // This line will override the previous position
            menuContainer.anchoredPosition3D = Vector3.Lerp(desiredMenuPosition, newDesiredPosition, enteringLevelZoomCurve.Evaluate(zoomTransition));

            // Fade to white screen , this will override the first line in the update 
            fadeGroup.alpha = zoomTransition;

            // Are we done with the animation 
            if(zoomTransition >= 1)
            {
                // Enter the level 
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
            }
        }

    } 

    private void InItShop()
    {
        // Just make sure we've assigned the referencess
        if (colorPanel == null || trailPanel == null)
            Debug.Log("You didnt not asign the color/trail panel in the inspector");

        //For every children transfrom under our color panel , find the button and add onClick
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Transform t in colorPanel)
        {
            int currentIndex = i;

            Button b = t.GetComponent<Button>();
            b.onClick.AddListener(() => OnColorSelect(currentIndex));

            // Set color of the image, based on if owned or not
            Image img = t.GetComponent<Image>();
            img.color = SaveManager.Instance.IsTrailOwned(i)
                ? Manager.Instance.playerColors[currentIndex]
                : Color.Lerp(Manager.Instance.playerColors[currentIndex], new Color(0, 0, 0, 1), 0.25f);

            i++;
        }
        //Reset index 
        i = 0;
        //Do the same for the trail 
        foreach (Transform t in trailPanel)
        {
            int currentIndex = i;

            Button b = t.GetComponent<Button>();
            b.onClick.AddListener(() => OnTrailSelect(currentIndex));

            // Set trail of the image, based on if owned or not
            RawImage img = t.GetComponent<RawImage>();
            img.color = SaveManager.Instance.IsColorOwned(i) ? Color.white : new Color (0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f);

            i++;
        }

        // Set the previous trail , to prevent bug when spawing later 
       // previousTrail = trailPanel.GetChild(SaveManager.Instance.state.activeTrail).GetComponent<RawImage>().texture;
    }

    private void InitLevel()
    {
        // Just make sure we've assigned the referencess
        if (levelPanel == null )
            Debug.Log("You didnt not asign the level panel in the inspector");

        //For every children transfrom under our level panel , find the button and add onClick
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Transform t in levelPanel)
        {
            int currentIndex = i;

            Button b = t.GetComponent<Button>();
            b.onClick.AddListener(() => OnLevelSelect(currentIndex));

            Image img = t.GetComponent<Image>();

            // Is it unlocked ?
            if (i <= SaveManager.Instance.state.completedLevel)
            {
                //It is unlocked!
                if(i == SaveManager.Instance.state.completedLevel)
                {
                    //It's not completed !
                    img.color = Color.white;
                }
                else
                {
                    // level is already completed !
                    img.color = Color.green;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Level isn't unlock , disable the button
                b.interactable = false;

                // Set to a dark color
                img.color = Color.grey; 
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    private void SetCameraTo(int menuIndex)
    {
        NavigateTo(menuIndex);
        menuContainer.anchoredPosition3D = desiredMenuPosition;
    }

    private void NavigateTo(int menuIndex)
    {
        switch(menuIndex)
        {
            // 0 && default case = main menu 
            default:
            case 0:
                desiredMenuPosition = Vector3.zero;
                menuCam.BackToMainMenu();
                break;
            // 1 = play menu
            case 1:
                desiredMenuPosition = Vector3.right * 1280;
                menuCam.MoveToLevel();
                break;
            // 2= shop menu
            case 2:
                desiredMenuPosition = Vector3.left * 1280;
                menuCam.MoveToShop();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void SetColor(int index)
    {
        // Set the active index 
        activeColorIndex = index;
        SaveManager.Instance.state.activeColor = index;

        //Change the color of the player 
        Manager.Instance.playerMaterial.color = Manager.Instance.playerColors[index];

        //change buy/set button text
        buyColorText.text = "Current";

        // Remember prefrences
        SaveManager.Instance.Save();
    }

    private void SetTrail(int index)
    {
        // Set the active index
        activeTrailIndex = index;
        SaveManager.Instance.state.activeTrail = index;

        //Change the trail of the player
        if (currentTrail != null)
            Destroy(currentTrail);

        // Create the new trail
        currentTrail = Instantiate(Manager.Instance.playertrails[index]) as GameObject;

        // Set it as a children of the player
        currentTrail.transform.SetParent(FindObjectOfType<MenuPlayer>().transform);

        // Fix the wierd scalling issues / rotation issues
        currentTrail.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        currentTrail.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);
        currentTrail.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * 0.01f; 

        //change buy/set button text
        buyTrailText.text = "Current";

        // Remember prefrences
        SaveManager.Instance.Save();
    }

    private void UpdateGoldText()
    {
        goldText.text = SaveManager.Instance.state.gold.ToString();
    }

    //Buttons
    public void OnPlayClick()
    {
        NavigateTo(1);
        Debug.Log("Play Button Has Been Clicked");
    }

    public void OnShopClick()
    {
        NavigateTo(2);
        Debug.Log("Your in the shop");
    }

    public void OnBackClick()
    {
        NavigateTo(0);
        Debug.Log("Back button has been clicked");
    }

    private void OnTrailSelect(int currentIndex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Selecting trail button : " + currentIndex);

        // If the button clicked is already selected, exist 
        if (selectedTrailIndex == currentIndex)
            return;

        // Preview trail
        // Get the image of the preview button
        //trailPanel.GetChild(selectedTrailIndex).GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = previousTrail;
        // Keep the new trails preview image in the previous trail
        //previousTrail = trailPanel.GetChild(currentIndex).GetComponent<RawImage>().texture;
        // Set the new trail preview image to the other camera
        //trailPanel.GetChild(currentIndex).GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = trailPreviewTexture;

        //  Change the physical object of the trail preview
       /* if (lastpreviewObject != null)
            Destroy(lastpreviewObject);
        lastpreviewObject = GameObject.Instantiate(Manager.Instance.playertrails[currentIndex]) as GameObject;
        lastpreviewObject.transform.SetParent(trailPreviewObject);
        lastpreviewObject.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;*/

        // Make the icon slightly bigger 
        trailPanel.GetChild(currentIndex).GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = Vector3.one * 1.125f;
        // Put the previuos one on normal scale
        trailPanel.GetChild(selectedTrailIndex).GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = Vector3.one;


        // Set the selected color 
        selectedTrailIndex = currentIndex;

        //Change the content of the buy/set button button , depending on the state of the color 
        if (SaveManager.Instance.IsTrailOwned(currentIndex))
        {
            // Trail is owned 
            // Is it already our current color ?
            if (activeTrailIndex == currentIndex)
            {
                buyTrailText.text = "Current";
            }
            else
            {
                buyTrailText.text = "Select";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Trail isnt owned
            buyTrailText.text = "Buy:" + trailCost[currentIndex].ToString();
        }
    }

    private void OnColorSelect(int currentIndex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Selecting Color button : " + currentIndex);

        // If the button clicked is already selected, exist 
        if (selectedColorIndex == currentIndex)
            return;

        // Make the icon slightly bigger 
        colorPanel.GetChild(currentIndex).GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = Vector3.one * 1.125f;
        // Put the previuos one on normal scale
        colorPanel.GetChild(selectedColorIndex).GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = Vector3.one;

        // Set the selected color 
        selectedColorIndex = currentIndex;

        //Change the content of the buy/set button button , depending on the state of the color 
        if(SaveManager.Instance.IsColorOwned(currentIndex))
        {
            // color is owned
            // Is it already our current color ?
            if(activeColorIndex == currentIndex)
            {
                buyColorText.text = "Current";
            }
            else
            {
                buyColorText.text = "Select";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            // Color isnt owned
            buyColorText.text = "Buy: " + colorCost[currentIndex].ToString();
        }
    }

    private void OnLevelSelect(int currentIndex)
    {
        Manager.Instance.currentLevel = currentIndex;
        isEnteringLevel = true;
        Debug.Log("Selecting level : " + currentIndex);
    }

    public void OnColorBuy()
    {
        Debug.Log("Buy color");

        // Is the selected color owned
        if(SaveManager.Instance.IsColorOwned(selectedColorIndex))
        {
            // Set the color !
            SetColor(selectedColorIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            // Attempt to buy the color 
            if (SaveManager.Instance.BuyColor(selectedColorIndex, colorCost[selectedColorIndex]))
            {
                // Success!
                SetColor(selectedColorIndex);

                // Change the color of the button 
                colorPanel.GetChild(selectedColorIndex).GetComponent<Image>().color = Manager.Instance.playerColors[selectedColorIndex];


                //Update gold text
                UpdateGoldText();
            }
            else
            {
                // Dont have enough gold
                // Play sound feedback  
                Debug.Log("Not enough gold");
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnTrailBuy()
    {
        Debug.Log("Buy Trail");

        // Is the selected trail owned
        if (SaveManager.Instance.IsTrailOwned(selectedTrailIndex))
        {
            // Set the trail !
            SetTrail(selectedTrailIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            // Attempt to buy the trail 
            if (SaveManager.Instance.BuyTrail(selectedTrailIndex, trailCost[selectedTrailIndex]))
            {
                // Success!
                SetTrail(selectedTrailIndex);

                // Change the color of the button 
                trailPanel.GetChild(selectedTrailIndex).GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;

                //Update gold text
                UpdateGoldText();
            }
            else
            {
                // Dont have enough gold
                // Play sound feedback  
                Debug.Log("Not enough gold");
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnTiltControl()
    {
        // Toggle the accelerometer bool 
        SaveManager.Instance.state.usingAccelerometer = !SaveManager.Instance.state.usingAccelerometer;

        // Make sure we save the player's preferences
        SaveManager.Instance.Save();

        // Change the display image of the tilt control button
        tiltControlButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = (SaveManager.Instance.state.usingAccelerometer) ? tiltControlEnabled : tiltControlDisabled;
    }

}
```

Plane Selection scrpit

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlaneSelection : MonoBehaviour {

    private GameObject[] characterList;

    private int index;

    private void Start()
    {
        index = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CharacterSelected");

        characterList = new GameObject[transform.childCount];

        // Fill the array with our models 
        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
            characterList[i] = transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;

        // We toggle off their render
        foreach (GameObject go in characterList)
            go.SetActive(false);

        // We toggle on the selected character
        if (characterList[index])
            characterList[index].SetActive(true);
    }

    public void ToggleLeft()
    {
        // Toggle off the current model
        characterList[index].SetActive(false);

        index--;//index -= 1 , index - 1;
        if (index < 0)
            index = characterList.Length - 1;

        // Toggle on the new model
        characterList[index].SetActive(true);
    }

    public void ToggleRight()
    {
        // Toggle off the current model
        characterList[index].SetActive(false);

        index++;//index -= 1 , index - 1;
        if (index == characterList.Length)
            index = 0;

        // Toggle on the new model
        characterList[index].SetActive(true);
    }

    public void ConfirmButton()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CharacterSelected", index);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }
}
```

Menu Camera script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MenuCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3 startPosition;
    private Quaternion startRotation;

    private Vector3 desiredPosition;
    private Quaternion desiredRotation;

    public Transform shopWaypoint;
    public Transform levelWaypoint;

    private void Start()
    {
        startPosition = desiredPosition = transform.localPosition;
        startRotation = desiredRotation = transform.localRotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float x = Manager.Instance.GetPlayerInput().x;

        transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localPosition, desiredPosition + new Vector3(0, x, 0) * 0.01f, 0.1f);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.localRotation, desiredRotation, 0.1f);
    }

    public void BackToMainMenu()
    {
        desiredPosition = startPosition;
        desiredRotation = startRotation;
    }

    public void MoveToShop()
    {
        desiredPosition = shopWaypoint.localPosition;
        desiredRotation = shopWaypoint.localRotation;
    }

    public void MoveToLevel()
    {
        desiredPosition = levelWaypoint.localPosition;
        desiredRotation = levelWaypoint.localRotation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your scene, are all the planes in the correct position inside edit mode? Toggle them on and off while running the game and see where they are. The buttons are not affecting their positions, they are not the cause of the problem.
I would reset the parent of the objects transform, and then place every single one of them in the correct place.